# python pairwise intersection in list

Tags: python-3.x

Having a list of sets, i would like to have a list that has  the intersection between the first set with the second, the second with the third and so on.
For example:

```
list_of_sets=[set([1,2,3,4,5]),set([1,2,3,5]),set([4,5,6])
meine_liste_len=len(list_of_sets) 
pairwise_intersection_list=[]  
for x in range(0,meine_liste_len-1):
    for y in range(1,meine_liste_len):
        pairwise_intersection_list.append(set x.intersection(set(y)))
```

I would like to have

```
 pairwise_intersection_list=set(([1,2,3]),([5]))
```

as result.

The first answer is a really good one which requires no import of a module. Another one (which uses zip) would be:

```
        pairwiseintersect_list=([i.intersection(j) for i,j inzip(list_of_sets,list_of_sets[1:])
```

Comment: What went wrong?

Comment: You want the final result to be a single set holding multiple lists? Lists aren't hashable, so that isn't going to work.

Comment: Consider posting a running example (or as close as possible). For example, `meine_liste_len` doesn't exist. If I'm going to post a solution I have to figure out what these variables are and add them in. You should do that work for us.

Comment: The final result wouldn't be [1, 2, 3, 5], [5] ?

Comment: @tdelaney i have the problem that it wouldn`t even calculate the rigth thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range(0, len(list_of_sets) - 1)` to get the index of all but the last member of the list. Then two adjacent sets are just index and index+1. Use that with a list comprehension and you get

```
>>> list_of_sets=[set([1,2,3,4,5]),set([1,2,3,5]),set([4,5,6])]
>>> new_list = [list_of_sets[i] & list_of_sets[i+1] for i in range(0, len(list_of_sets)-1)]
>>> new_list
[{1, 2, 3, 5}, {5}]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I didn't even knew one could use "&" in a function.